# Removing a contact from a folder in Yosemite Contacts software

Tags: macos

I created a folder in the Yosemite Contacts program and added some people to it. I'd like to remove a contact from the folder but keep the contact in my overall contacts database.

How do I do this?  The delete button deletes it completely.

Here is what I see if I select a name in a group and press delete.  I don't get the dialog box above with the "Remove from Groups" option:

[image]

If I select the contact and use the Edit menu the "Remove from Group" item is greyed out:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really seem to belong on SO. It should be on the Apple Stackexchange.

Comment: There's an Apple Stackexchange?  I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you edit the contact?

Comment: The reason I ask that was I suspect its a permission issue. You can try the normal `Disk Utility.app` repair permissions or try the suggestion on this page I just found. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5011903  There is to much in there for me to repost as an answer and I have not tried it. But try `Disk Utility.app` first.

Comment: The permission idea was a good clue, and I figured it out, will post answer below.

Answer (score 1):

There's a **Remove From Group** Menu item.

Select Your contact in the Group and open `Edit` -> `Remove From Group`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By Folder I think you mean Group.

When you hit the delete button or use the Menu. Contacts.app will give you a choice of deleting the Contact (card) from everywhere or just the Group.

You should choose the **Remove from group**. This will then only Remove it from the group and not delete it from the Contacts.

[image]

Comment: Strange. I don't see groups in Yosemite. I only see "Folders." and I did not see the dialog box. Did I set something up wrong?

Comment: What app are you using? Show some screen shots

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was creating my groups within an Exchange account.   If I made the groups in the "On my Mac" area then the "Remove from Group" functionality works normally.